# Do E-Mails get linked/traced to each other in any way?

Tags: email

If I look at the raw payload of the e-mail with the headers and all,
does it have a link to the e-mail I replied to or forwarded?
Or is that grouping purely done by the client by inspecting the subject name and contents?

For example, gmail will make a thread and hide the previous text since it's redundant.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about how emails are related to each other and not about running a website.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. Thought it was a more targeted space than stackoverflow.

Comment: E-mail threads are maintained in a varieties of ways. Essentially, you are talking about e-mail list applications. This is done on the server side using a variety of clues including from and to addresses as well as reply-to. How one particular site does this is not always evident. I used more than one application to maintain e-mail lists and make them available on the web. Getting into details is too much for this site. You will simply have to research, learn, test, and possibly code a solution. Like we all had to.